# Magento 2: log slow queries

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.1, performance, log

Back in M1 you could log the slow queries by modifying the following variables in `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` :

```
/**
  * Write SQL debug data to file
  *
  * @var bool
  */
 protected $_debug               = false;
 /**
  * Minimum query duration time to be logged
  *
  * @var unknown_type
  */
 protected $_logQueryTime        = 0.05;
 /**
  * Log all queries (ignored minimum query duration time)
  *
  * @var bool
  */
 protected $_logAllQueries       = false;
 /**
  * Add to log call stack data (backtrace)
  *
  * @var bool
  */
 protected $_logCallStack        = false;
 /**
  * Path to SQL debug data log
  *
  * @var string
  */
 protected $_debugFile           = 'var/debug/sql.txt';
```

So I'm wondering how can I do that in M2? I've found some interesting stuff in `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Logger/LoggerAbstract` as well as `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Logger/File` but I ain't 100% sure how to tackle this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`app/etc/di.xml` has the following preference set

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\Quiet"/>
```

Add your own module to change the preference to the file logger you mentioned with

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\DB\LoggerInterface" type="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File"/>
```

You should also be able to change the params via the same `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="debugFile" xsi:type="string">debug/db-custom.log</argument>
        <argument name="logAllQueries" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
        <argument name="logQueryTime" xsi:type="number">0.01</argument>
        <argument name="logCallStack" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Sweet I knew it would involve some DI changes. Good to know. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I believe that the "xsi:type" for the arguments "logAllQueries" and "logCallStack" should be "boolean" and not "bool".

Comment: Thanks @AndrewStayart - fixed. Looks like 2.2 might have some more changes in store https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.0-preview/app/etc/di.xml#L1321